# OpenCV VideoCapture out of X11

Tags: opencv, capture

This may be a strange situation. We have a PC-104 with only 2 GB hdd. So no Ubuntu linux can be installed on but the Server Edition (only text, no X11).

OpenCV can be installed directly from the repo, or they can be compiled from source. In both cases the VideoCapture objects can't open the camera streaming.

I guess this is that we don't have the X11 support, even if camera are listed in `/proc/bus/input/devices` and `/dev/video0` exists.

May any of you help me in this task? Obviously I accept any other Linux solution, take in mind we have only 2 GB hdd!!!

Thank you very much... hope you can help :-)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [gstreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/) for this task. GStreamer brings a command line application named **gst-launch** that you can use to test several features of the API.

Unfortunately, there's no native way to build OpenCV without some kind of X. But you can download the source code and follow through the function calls to implement your own library to handle the camera.